# Debian 8 iptables-persistent setup is not correct?

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, iptables-persistent

I'm renting a vps with debian 8 on it.
I'm trying to set up my `iptables`, following this blog:

http://bencane.com/2012/09/iptables-linux-firewall-rules-for-a-basic-web-server/

The problem is that my setup doesn't seem to be correct.

I first update my server by apt-get update
Then I add the rules to `iptables`, install `iptables-persistent` but trying to do the command
`iptables-persistent` save and I get "is a directory" rather than the saving process... when I install iptables-persistent this saves the ipv4 ipv6 settings, and using cat `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` I see my rules.

There is a last step typing in the command `ls -la /etc/rc2.d/ | grep iptables` should show something but mine does not.

in my `/etc/init.d/` directory I'm supposed to have `iptables-persistent` but it's actually in `/usr/share/doc/` so I moved it to `/etc/init.d/` but this does not seem to solve the problem as trying the command `/etc/init.d/iptables` save does not work, I get "is a directory" I think it is supposed to be a script file.

I'm not really sure what is going on.

The contents of `iptables-persistent` is a .gz changelog file so that's probably why the command doesn't work right?

Comment: If your sure it's a binary file (or shell script), why not change the file type via chmod (`sudo chmod (-rwxr-xr-x|0755) /etc/init.d/iptables`)? And if it isn't an executable, have you checked inside the directory?

Comment: @Krii As the error messages say, it's not a file but a directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation you have linked is outdated. The binary package you need [is now named `netfilter-persistent`](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=sourcenames&keywords=iptables-persistent). But don't worry, you have it already installed because `iptables-persistent` is now a plugin to `netfilter-persistent`, which was installed with it. So everything was okay and you should really move the documentation directory back to where it belongs.

Concerning the usage: Just replace all calls to `iptables-persistent` with `netfilter-persistent` and it should work as advertised.

(But you probably [should set](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=764645) `chmod go-rwx /etc/iptables` to make the directory containing the rules not readable for anyone except root.)

Comment: yeap the saving worked. thanks for the information!